# React Native Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, react-native

I was just wondering if it's possible to have email and password auth with react native? Also is there any tutorials out there for this topic?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use Firebase email+password auth with React Native, although there are some edge cases (the auth state won't be persisted across restarts). But "asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Ok Sounds Good, Would you reccomend the ios tutorials or javascript?

Comment: As said: recommendations for off-site resources are off topic. But this seems particularly relevant: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2016-01-20-tutorial-firebase-react-native.html

Comment: *Auth0* also provide a completely solution fot authentication using React Native. You can see this tutorial: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native-ios

Answer (score 2):

The following library allows you to easily do this: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase

Once signed in, auth state is persisted across app restarts/boots as it interacts with the native SDKs. On app boot, simply do the following to know whether the user is already signed in or not:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log(user);
    });
  }
```

Comment: you should disclose that you are the author of said library